# Why Telerik web reporting is sending multiple request.?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, telerik-reporting

I'm using Telerik Reporting with MVC, but I had an Issue with the requests count sent when the report is rendering, as u can see in the screenshot there is at leat 5-6 request sent, is there is any way so I can make the Whole report one request ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik Reporting keeps sending this info request while the server is generating the report.

While its generating, the response is:

```
bookmarkNodes: null
documentMapAvailable: false
documentReady: false
pageCount: 0
```

When it finishes responds with documentReady = true

```
bookmarkNodes: null
documentMapAvailable: false
documentReady: true
pageCount: 1
```

And finally it sends the last one request, to the page number initially requested.

---

Edit:

If you need to send less request to this info endpoint, it should be possible to override this method in your controller.

```
HttpResponseMessage GetDocumentInfo(string clientID, string instanceID, string documentID)
```

Comment: How to make it send less requests by overriding the Action..? can u please explain further more..?